# Shift an ordered Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying insert a number in an ordered array. In order to accomplish this i search for the last number that is less or equal to the searched number. From there i want to move that part of the array to the right.

```
int lowerBound = 0;
int upperBound = nElems.length-1;
int curIn = 0;
boolean check = true;
while(check)
{
    curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound ) / 2;
    if(nElems[curIn] == replaceKey)
    {
        for(int i = nElems.length - 2; i >= curIn - 1; i--)
        {
            nElems[i + 1] = nElems[i];
        }
        nElems[curIn] = replaceKey;
        check = false;// found it
    }
    else if (lowerBound > upperBound)
    {
        for(int i = nElems.length - 2; i >= curIn - 1; i--)
        {
            nElems[i + 1] = nElems[i];
        }
        nElems[curIn] = replaceKey;
        check = false;// found it
        //return nElems; // can’t find it
    }
    else // divide range
    {
        if (curIn < replaceKey)
        {
            lowerBound = curIn + 1; // it’s in upper half
        }
        else
        {
            upperBound = curIn - 1; // it’s in lower half
        }
    } // end else divide range
} // end while
```

The problem is when i try for example to insert the number 7 the outcome is this:

Before:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
0
```

After:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
7
28
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but a general (and important) hint: Split this into *two* methods: One that searches the insertion index, and one that does the insertion. (You could also clarify what should happen to the element that may be dropping out on the right side...)

Comment: I know, i was going to do that later on. I am going to try this, thank you! @pzaenger Java

Comment: Not enough to fix your problem, but you probably want to do `if (nElems[curIn] < replaceKey)`, not `if (curIn < replaceKey)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace your test in the divide range section of your code by

```
if(nElems[curIn] < replaceKey)
```

You were comparing the index of insertion with the key to insert. In fact, what you were doing was to insert `replaceKey` **at index** `replaceKey`. In your example, 7 was inserted at rank 6 (it would have been inserted at rank 7 if 28 was not the last element of your array).

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel and not use a TreeSet?

```
    Collection<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 0);

    SortedSet<Integer> sortedNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>(nums);

    sortedNumbers.add(7);

    System.out.println(sortedNumbers); // [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 15, 21, 28]
```

Answer (score -1):

We have to free the point where we have to insert. To make free we need to move every element that is on or after desired location to its next location. For that the best solution is available below.
The solution that is in question is not working because it have no statement for the value that have to be inserted before mid.

Why are you using such a complex code. Lets see

```
int x=7;int i; for(i = nElems.length - 2; i >=0; i--) { if(nElems[i]>x) nElems[i + 1] = nElems[i]; } nElems[i]=x;
```

This code will insert the element x at the desired position.

Comment: It's not very helpful to paste some code and tell the OP this works. Why does it work and more importantly, why doesn't his version work.

Comment: Your code is totally invalid. You are checking if the element to insert is at middle or before middle of array. No code if the element to insert after middle.

Comment: If you want to use that code you have to modify a huge.

Comment: Are you criticizing yourself now?

Comment: No i am saying that the solution you are using have many issues. Complex code. High time. Wrong output. Only correction will take a huge modifications.

Comment: LOL, what solution? My comment is still valid though. Please focus on that.

Comment: Best solution is the solution in my answer.

Comment: Get some sleep. I feel you need it.

Comment: I could not understand what you want?

Comment: The solution that i have posted moves every element that is after insertion point, to its next location. The solution that is in question is not working because it have no statement for the value that have to be inserted before mid.

Comment: Just read my first comment. I only asked you to explain your answer. Why does it work etc. Just saying: "hey, this code will work" doesn't help much. That is all.

Comment: Ok, include that piece of explaination in your answer :-)

Comment: For insertion we first need to free the location and for that we have to move every element after insertion point to its next location.

Comment: That's a lot better. Thank you for updating